Electron Store working in dev mode but not in production
I am using Electron Store in Electron Js Project. The app is successfully built. But the electron store is not working in production/build version as I am not able to store the data persistently. What could be the reason for this?
ipcMain.handle("get-store-value", async (event, key) => {
  return store.get(key);
});

ipcMain.handle("set-store-value", async (event, key, value) => {
  store.set(key, value);
});

ipcMain.handle("delete-store-value", async (event, key) => {
  store.delete(key);
});

useEffect(() =\> {
  const fetchData = async () =\> {
    try {
      const nodesData = await ipcRenderer.invoke(
        "get-store-value",
        "nodes",
      );

      const edgesData = await ipcRenderer.invoke(
        "get-store-value",
        "edges",
      );
    
      // console.log("Fetched nodes:", nodesData);
      // console.log("Fetched edges:", edgesData);
    
      setNodes(JSON.parse(nodesData));
      setEdges(JSON.parse(edgesData));
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      setNodes([]);
      setEdges([]);
    }
  };
    
  fetchData();
}, []);

I am using this code in main js file and using ipcRenderer to invoke this function in jsx file.
